# Changing the "arrow style" of arrow

Tags: tikz-arrows

When writing math I like the arrows that are formed by using the math font `pxfonts` and the command `\tikzcdset{arrows={line width=rule_thickness},arrow style=math font}` that actually changes the arrows. However, I don't actually like the math font `pxfonts` but it's needed to get the arrows I like. Thus, my question is; how can I get the arrows I like but use default math font?

To add, I want to *remove* the math font `pxfonts`, but when I do so, I no longer get the arrows I like since the command `\tikzcdset{arrows={line width=rule_thickness},arrow style=math font}` needs the math font `pxfonts`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you only need a `Straight Barb` arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\tikzcdset{
    arrow style=tikz,
    diagrams={>={Straight Barb[scale=0.7]}}
    }

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
a \ar[r]& b&c\ar[l]\\
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to set this type of arrow in the entire document? Say for \to, \mapsto...

Comment: @EstebanSaldarriaga I think you can redefine the `\to` and `\mapsto` commands using TikZ. If you don't know how, please ask another question with a minimal example and the link at this one as a benchmark.